# How can I change the font of a pdf file?

Tags: fonts, pdf

I would love to change the default font that comes with a pdf that I have. I would like to pick one from my system font cache. How I can do that?

I normally use Evince but any pdf reader will be fine if it will support custom fonts.

Answer (score 4):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think that's possible. The nature of a PDF file is that the layout is fixed so that it always looks the same.

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format): "Each PDF file **encapsulates a complete description of a fixed-layout** flat document, including the text, **fonts**, graphics, and other information needed to display it".

---

If you want to edit the PDFs you could try [this](http://www.howtoforge.com/editing_pdf_files_pdfedit_ubuntu_feisty_p2) (first hit on Google), or just search for another PDF editor.

Comment: the fact that is defined does not mean that i can't change it, it's like buying a blue car and saying that you can't re-paint it with a red color. For what i know this is possible in theory, also the language used in a pdf is more like an interpreted language and the pdf reader is an interpreter .

Comment: Well that analogy isn't entirely accurate cause you don't want to change the PDF file, right? So it's more like buying a car and wanting it to be red for you but blue for everyone else.

The same question has been asked [here](http://www.theologyweb.com/campus/showthread.php?113093-font-change-in-pdf-reader), [here](http://uk.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20081212091720AAFrnEi) and [here](http://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=107534); the answers are pretty much the same as mine.

Answer (score 0):

I use masterPDF to edit pdf files it's not part of Ubuntu but works well and can be downloaded from [here.](https://code-industry.net/get-masterpdfeditor/)

Download the .deb file install with software installer.